# Ruby, How to create an n size array of random float from 0 to 1

Tags: ruby

I know that i can create a random float by calling rand() to generate a (psuedo-)random float between 0 and 1. But what is the best way to create an array of size n of random float between 0 and 1 without using a loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would do:

```
Array.new(n) { rand }
```

Comment: Found the answer but thanks! will uptick it as soon as the counters done!